# Allow only specific cookies (i.e. cookies with a specific name) to pass zuul filter

Tags: java, cookies, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I would like to allow only a specific cookie to pass Zuul into the microservice,
Is there a way to allow such configuration while keep cookie as sensitive header?

For Exmaple:

I have a cookie named: "testCookie" I would like to allow the cookie with that name into the demo-service, I still want to regard all other cookies as sensitive headers(and filter them), Zuul configuration example for a service(in yml file):

```
  demo-service:
      path: /api/demo/**
      service-id: demo-service
      sensitive-headers: Cookie,Set-Cookie
```

Is that possible?

p.s it is reverse to the ignoredHeaders field in zuul as it can discard specific headers

Many thanks.

Comment: There is no such configuration. You would need to write a custom ZuulFilter.

Comment: Thanks @spencergibb , big fan, I will create a custom filter